PostgreSQL Window Function with equality predicate
I have the following query in PostgreSQL.  Everything works as expected.  It returns a single row for each grp.  The row returned has the greatest id within the grp.
with tbl1(id, grp, name) as (
values
(1, 1, 'name1'),
(2, 1, 'name2'),
(3, 2, 'name3'),
(4, 2, 'name4')
)SELECT 
    id = max(id) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) as is_max,
    id, grp, name
    from tbl1
    ;

is_max |id |grp|name |
-------+---+---+-----+
false  |1  |1  |name1|
true   |2  |1  |name2|
false  |3  |2  |name3|
true   |4  |2  |name4|

Going over the PostgreSQL Window Function documentation I can't find any reference to this.  Does anyone know where I can find some references/documentation for this?

It's just an equality check, same as select 1=1 which returns a boolean.

@Isolated you're right ....
I think this is the only use case I've seen the equality check have some meaning in the primary SQL statement at the end.

On a side note, row_number() over (partition by grp order by id desc) = 1 is probably more efficient

I'm  using PostgreSQL 16.1 and query working perfectly.
Check windows function in PostgreSQL
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html
Alternative way to resolve the issue:
with tbl1(id, grp, name) as (
values
    (1, 1, 'name1'),
    (2, 1, 'name2'),
    (3, 2, 'name3'),
    (4, 2, 'name4')
)
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN(id = (max(id) OVER (PARTITION BY grp))) 
           THEN true 
        ELSE false 
    END as is_max,
    
    id = (max(id) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)) AS is_max2,
    
    id, grp, name
    from tbl1


Sample Code: 
PlpgSQL:
db<>fiddle
MySQL: db<>fiddle
